# cms blocks removing content after save in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, html, cms-block, tags

> cms block break html tags after saving data.
> it is removing  url of image and display like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<a href="#">
    <img class="lazyload"  src="{{media url=" data-original="{{media url=" />
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the result but where is the core template ? Where this html is build ? Looks like to a simple `"` instead of `'` issue to me.

Comment: This is happening in admin CMS block\